# Using sys.argv to declare the file name for the .csv output of script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I'm struggling to get this code to create a .csv file with a filename that I declare through the second argument I make when using cmd+r to run my script. Right now I've managed to get it to get the script to accept the first argument when typing:

> winkey+r -> pyscript https://stackoverflow.com

but when I type:

> winkey+r -> pyscript https://stackoverflow.com ideal_filename.csv

Nothing really happens. I'm still getting the output to my clipboard, but it's not creating a new .csv file. If I manually name the file within the script it works fine, but makes the script a bit less functional.

I'm not really sure what to do here -- I only recently started learning and got some help getting to here.

Full code is as follows:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pyperclip
import sys
import pandas as pd

sys.argv
url = sys.argv[1]
docTitle = sys.argv[2]

try:
    session = HTMLSession()
    response = session.get(url)

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
    print(error)

def crawl(url, docTitle=docTitle):
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    csv_from_soup(soup, output_filename=docTitle)
    
def csv_from_soup(soup, output_filename, print_to_console=True):
    title = soup.find('title')
    desc = soup.findAll(attrs={"name": "description"})
    h1Tag = soup.find_all('h1')[0].text.strip()
    metadata = {
        'Canonical' : response.html.xpath("//link[@rel='canonical']/@href"),
        'Page Title': title.string,
        'PT Length': len(title.string),
        'Meta Description': desc[0]['content'],
        'MD Length': len(desc[0]['content']),
        'H1 Tag': h1Tag,
    }
    metadata_strings = ["\n".join([str(k), str(v)]) for k,v in metadata.items()]
    metadata_strings = '\n--------------\n'.join(metadata_strings)
    tag_names = ["h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"]
    tag_data = [(tags.name + ' ',' ' + tags.text.strip()) for tags in soup.find_all(tag_names)]
    tag_df = pd.DataFrame(tag_data, columns=["H1-H6 Tags", " Text"])
    full_csv = "\n\n".join([metadata_strings, tag_df.to_csv(index=False)])
    pyperclip.copy(full_csv)
    if print_to_console:
        print(full_csv)
    with open(output_filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(full_csv.encode('utf-8', errors='replace'))
    return full_csv

crawl(url)
```

Comment: Where are you typing these commands?

Comment: It suspect you aren't looking in the correct directory for the output file. The current working directory isn't necessarily the directory in which your script is stored. Add `import os; print(os.getcwd())` to see where your script is saving the file.

Comment: @DanielWalker - I'm just typing [winkey + r] the pyfile name, URL, and ideal-filename

Comment: For those of us who know Python but not Windows, knowing that you typed winkey + r doesn't really answer the question about where you're looking for the output file, nor the one about what the current working directory is for commands run that way and thus where you _should_  look for the output file (which is a Windows end-user question, not a Python question or a software development question).

Comment: @chepner - I added that code in but in order for me to see what that output was I had to remove the sys.argv values and replace that with the actual URL & name of the CSV. Once I did that, the console indicated that it's being saved to the working directory of the script. I'm not sure how to test that without adding the URL & file name into the script directly

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Fair point. After following the instructions chepner suggested I can see that when I declare the values in the script directly it saves to the working directory. I'm not sure how best to describe what I'm seeing. Forgive me for being new!

Comment: Sorry, "working directory of the script"? (Scripts don't _have_ working directories as a property of the script itself -- the working directory of a process is whatever directory the process that started it was using, unless that program changes to the script's directory while starting it; maybe the Windows shell does that, but... well, a lot of us are UNIX people, and we don't know how Windows works).

Comment: ...anyhow, where I'd probably start is to hardcode an absolute path to somewhere you can write logs. If you write `repr(sys.argv)`, `repr(os.getcwd())` and other relevant strings to a file, that'll do a lot of good in terms of having the information necessary to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Good point! Something for me to keep in mind. At any rate, getcwd() did in fact point me in the right way. I wrote that into my print function, figured out there was no path. Then used os.chdir() to write the output where I wanted. Thanks for the help and info!